# how to make request to twilio with urllib2 or requests without python sdk

Tags: python, python-requests, twilio, urllib2, twilio-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to Twilio api using requests but it returns 401 status code every time , whats the problem?

```
url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe3a9b......27812bc6/Messages'
values = {  
        'To' : '+XXXXX' , 
        'From' : '+XXXXXX' ,
        'Body' : 'XXXX' ,
        }

headers             = {'AuthToken' :'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' , 
                    'AccountSid' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' } 


response        = requests.post(url , data = values  , headers = headers )
```

thanks

Comment: what is the details of the response?

Comment: hi , 
{ 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'ETag', 'Twilio-Request-Id': 'ssss', 'X-Powered-By': 'AT-5000', 'Twilio-Request-Duration': '0.006', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Date': 'Tue, 07 Nov 2017 16:30:45 GMT', 'X-Shenanigans': 'none', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Twilio API"

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but take a look at the Twilio Python Helper Library. The docs are found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python)

Comment: I read the docs , I want to make an api call without relying on twilio sdk for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Twilio's REST API requires HTTP Basic Auth.  Ditch the headers and replace it with...

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('AccountSid', 'AuthToken')
response = requests.post(url, data = values, auth = auth)
```